# Angular - parser error from response

Tags: angular

When the sent data is bad, it gets from the server tables with validator errors, as you can see in the picture. My question is how to get to this array so that you do not have to refer to each element individually on reasonably err.error.erros.email or err.error.erros.password. I would like to display these errors using sweetalert, one below the other.

My code:

```
 this.http.post('https://mylocalhost/api/1.3/user/login', params, {headers: config})
        .subscribe(res => {
                this.userData = res;
                swal('App', 'Zostałeś zalogowany pomyślnie', 'success');
                localStorage.setItem('x-ticket', this.userData['x-ticket']);
            },
            (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: which angular version are you using?

Comment: So you just need an easy way to get those errors?

Comment: @argo i use angular 6

Comment: @Volodymyr Khmil yes, i need simple way. Although in time I would like to do, maybe some service that I will be hooking up and he will parse these errors.

Comment: Did you try catchError() from rxJs, and inside extract your errors
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html

Comment: I have posted the code which I use to show exception, with minor tweaking I guess it would work for you too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to convert it into an array

```js
var error = {
  errors: {
     email: "This is an email error",
     password: "This is a password error"
  }
}


// Create an array from the object
let arr = Object.keys(error.errors).map((key) => error.errors[key]);

// Some examples of using the value
console.log(arr);
console.log(arr[0]);
console.log(arr.join("\n"));
```

Once you have an array, you can then display those however you wish without needing to refer to each error type.

Comment: Works perfect :D Thank for help

Answer (score 0):

Below is one of the angular 5 code examples I'm using. You should be able to edit and and make it work in your case.

```
postNewInventoryEntry(data: any) {
    return this.http.post(this.api_url + '/inventory-management/inventory/', data)
      .map(res => res)
      .catch((e: any) => {
      alert('ERROR: ' + e.error['msg']);
      return _throw(e.error)});
  }
```